# Solve $\int (y^4+by^2+c)^{-1/2}dy=x$ as $y$ is a real valued function of $x$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, irreducible-polynomials

Solve $\int (y^4+by^2+c)^{-1/2}dy=x$ as y is a real valued function of x. Here $b$ and $c$ are real constants so that $c>b^2/4$.

Comment: Your $y$ is a real number as well or $y\inℂ$?

Comment: If the integrand ever takes complex values, it is almost certain that the result will be complex. For the complex values to cancel out, there would need to be some symmetry.

Comment: If $c>b^2/4$ then $y^4+by^2+c$ never vanishes for $y\in\mathbb{R}$, hence the integral is real.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Delta=b^2-4c<0$. Then $y^4+by^2+c$ never vanishes for $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^4+by^2+c}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{u^2+bu+c}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{\left(u+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-\frac{\Delta}{4}}}$$
is real and bounded by (assuming $b\neq 0$):
$$\int_{0}^{|b|}\frac{2 du}{\sqrt{-\Delta u}}+\int_{|b|}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}\left(u-\frac{|b|}{2}\right)}=4\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{-\Delta}}+\log(1+\sqrt{2})\sqrt{\frac{8}{|b|}}.$$